# Why is it mandatory for a class to be abstract when it has atleast one abstract method?

Tags: java, abstract-methods

What is the reason that I can't create a concrete class with abstract methods in it?

Is it enforced just to make sure that no object is created without abstract method definition? or is there another plausible reason for this restriction?

Comment: The title is not clear to me.

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're asking. Are you suggesting that we should be able to declare concrete classes with abstract methods? Note that you can already declare abstract classes where every method is concrete...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am asking the other way. i.e. to declare concrete class with abstract methods.

Comment: @badmad: Well how could that make sense? What would happen if you created an instance and then called the abstract method? *Why* do you want to do that?

Comment: @JonSkeet I suppose that "abstract" is less keystrokes than " throws { new UnsupportedOperationException(); }" which is what in my mind would happen if you called the abstract method (if it were allowed).  Not a compelling case for allowing a non-abstract class to have abstract methods, but it is not ludicrous either.

Comment: @emory: Definitely not a compelling case IMO - but not one that the OP has even made. The OP should at least edit the question to show that they've considered the implications...

Comment: @JonSkeet Assume that I would correctly override all the abstract methods in the dervied class and I would never call the abstract method of superclass instance. With this assumption, would it have been possible to create a concrete class with abstract methods?

Comment: @badmad: Language specifications can't be written with "assume I never do X" in mind. They have to specify what *would* happen in those corner cases (or at least they should). It's still not clear why you want to do this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there anything in the underlying memory model of the language that restricts this?

Comment: It's not really a memory model issue, but I suspect the VM is built on the assumption that this won't happen.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would think it that way too. As far as I understand now, this restriction was placed not for any technical reason but to avoid coding errors.

Comment: You make it sound like "to avoid coding errors" is only a minor reason. There are *lots* of aspects of Java which are only there "to avoid coding errors", such as the inability to read from a local variable before it's definitely assigned.

Comment: I didn't intend to mean that. I was trying to differentiate both of those reasons.

Answer (score 1):

An `abstract` class is, by definition, incomplete. Therefore, you should not be able to instantiate `abstract` classes. An interesting side effect of this definition is that you can create `abstract` classes that have all concrete methods. It's just that you think that your class is incomplete and shouldn't be able to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

`abstract` class in the java constext is defined as the class has at least one 
`abstract` method. And an abstract method is just a not implemented method. This is a design decision that was just copied from c++ where it is exactly the same. The only difference is, that in c++ you do not need to tell the compiler that a class is abstract, the compiler knows it even without you telling it. Why this design decision was made in c++ I can't tell you, but having it eleminates a complete class of errors. The error that a method of a class get's called, when the method is not implemented in that sub class.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the reason is to prevent creating an object with no implementation for a method or more.

Comment: my question was more towards why is this restriction placed? what was the need?

Comment: ok, so Micheel's anwer might have already done it for you. But anyway here's my try: Abstract is a generalization that is never meant to be instantiated. It is intended to define methods that its non abstract specializations must implement to be able to provide a specific behavior for that specialization. Any behavior that is common to all the specializations, could be implemented in the abstract class itself, so that it need not be repeated...Let me know if you need examples, I can elaborate my answer if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you create an Abstract class you are in the middle of your abstractions level. i Mean you have some questions about class responsibilities or this class must to do something but they dont care how, partially. If you dont wanna have an implemented method, you must to create an interface.
In my opinion the answer is in the class responsibilities and abstraction and not in the technology scope.